# Adding words to a 'Dictionary' at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dictionary

I have created a dictionary like this:

```
Private WordMDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String())

Public Sub wordget()
    WordMDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String())
    WordMDictionary.Add("Money", {"Money- Psychologically value added binary code or paper", "Cash - same meaning as money"})
End Sub
```

How can I add to this dictionary at runtime using textboxes to add a word and its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `TextBox` for a word and another `TextBox`(multiline) for it's meanings.

```
WordMDictionary(txtWord.Text) = txtMeanings.Lines
```

So one line is one meaning.

Comment: so saving this using My.setting would be done using what method?

Comment: @AltCoder: Sorry, i havent understood your last question.

Comment: sorry I didnt explain myself.
basically I need to be able to save the words that i enter into the dictionary so that when i start up the application i wont need to add them back

Comment: @AltCoder: I would use a database. However, there is no dictionary that you can store in the settings. So one workaround would be to use a row- and column-delimiter and store a single string. Then you can use `String.Split` to get your original word+array.

Comment: I see. a Database would be beat . it will allow users to add words and meanings easily and depending on what i'm doing with the words and meanings i may need to simply feed the database data to the dictionary .